# WINE uninstall from system

Tags: linux, wine

I've installed WINE on my system by compiling and installing it from source code. Now I am trying to uninstall it but it won't let me.

When I do `dnf remove wine*`, it just says "Nothing to do". Any suggestions on how I can remove wine completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design, package managers only manage the software which was installed with them. To remove the software which was installed with `dnf instal ...` you must use `dns remove ...`.

They won't manage the software installed by hand (using `make install` and so on). To remove that, you need to know which files were installed when you run `make install` and manually remove them.

Often the building system provides a `make uninstall` or something like that, which will remove anything for you. But that'll help only if you kept your building directory.

---

I know, that's extremely cumbersome and inconvenient. That's the price you pay for installing something around the system package manager. The lesson here is: *never do this, always use a package manager to install packages into production system*. In particular, when you need to build something from the source, you always build a packet and then install it properly using `rpm -i` or `dpkg -i` etc, you name it; never run just `make install`. Yes, this is more work, but this will save you from cumbersome and error-prone cleaning guts and tails of programs that you might have installed manually.

Comment: Make uninstall didn't remove it properly, I can still run the command wine64.

Comment: A hint: if Makefile suports installing under a prefix (e.g. `DESTDIR=/tmp/wine-makeinstall make install` installs everything under /tmp/wine-makeinstall instead of the system), you can try to perform this step to determine what it had installed, then compare with the files in the system. But this is error-prone, there can be collisions and so on.